# Datetime decremented in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I sent my datetime to server and it works fine.But when i got it it decremented by 1.
Sent '2020-06-12T00:00:000Z' and got '2020-06-11T00:00:000Z',any idea will be greate.

Comment: Is there any conversion with utc time or local time?

Comment: @JahidulIslam no i just get the date from user and send it to server

Comment: what about your json response? can you share it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a bug on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

In dealing with Date and Time, you need to be consistent with the format or system you're using to.
It's ideal to use UTC to get the actual date and time when passing DateTime values.

```
/// Converts  `DateTime` to `int` in milliseconds since Epoch (Unix).
  static int convertDateTimeToInteger(DateTime dateTime) {
    return (dateTime.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000).toInt();
  }
```

In this method, you can save the value of the DateTime (from client's) to your server-side as an integer.

```
  /// Converts `int` to `DateTime` format and
  /// returns `[String]` data type.
  ///
  /// Default Format: MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm
  static String convertIntUnixToString(int date, {DateFormat formatterDate}) {
    /// Convert the integer back to datetime.
    var dateInUnix = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(date * 1000).toUtc();

    /// Format/Customize the DateTime.
    if (formatterDate == null) {
      formatterDate = DateFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy').add_jm();
    }

    var formattedDate = formatterDate.format(dateInUnix);
    return formattedDate;
  }
```

Now you can retrieve it and display it using this function which you can pass some custom date formatter.